# MacBook Pro camera not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, webcam

I've tried the solution on this website https://medium.com/@racter/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-a-retina-macbook-11-2-74e7779c0e47:

```
$ cd /etc/local/src
$ git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
$ cd bcwc_pcie/firmware
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ cd ..
$ sudo make
$ sudo install
$ sudo depmod
$ sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
$ sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

However, I get the following error after the first **sudo make**.

```
Checking dependencies for driver download...
/usr/bin/xzcat
/bin/cpio
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'AppleCameraInterface' failed
make: *** [AppleCameraInterface] Error 1
```

Comment: Use `less -N Makefile` and see what line 34 references. Execute `sudo lshw` (read `man lshw`) to see what the system thinks your camera is. BTW, Your `sudo install` line is probably incorrect.

Comment: I am also getting this. Checking dependencies for driver download...
/usr/bin/xzcat
/bin/cpio
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'AppleCameraInterface' failed
make: *** [AppleCameraInterface] Error 1
Speculation: is there some kind of hash? I though I read I should have gotten some kind of file from MacOS [well I've already deleted it! Ubuntu 100% - am I screwed?]

Comment: Line #34: https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: This does not work for me. I have Macbook White 2009 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. What works is by using isight firmware installer. Ask me how.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**
The firmware repository was moved to a separate repository. The procedure now is

```bash
cd /etc/local/src
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie/firmware
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware
cd facetimehd-firmware
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ../..
sudo make
sudo make install   # (Update with make install for 18.04)    
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

Comment: The only change for me on MacBook Pro Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, `cd /usr/local/src` and adding `facetimehd` in `/etc/modules` and reboot.

Comment: After upate of the kernel I got this error when calling `modprobe facetimehd`: `modprobe: FATAL: Module facetimehd not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-134-generic`. Worked again after redoing the procedure in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing curl. I also got the same problem and then I figured out that it is because curl is not installed default in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: `sudo make` does not import the proxy variables from your .bashrc. Run `sudo -E make` (if you are behind proxy).

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm this works on Macbook Pro 13 mid 2014. 
My src folder was in /usr/local

Doesn't run after reboot. Apparently need to update the /etc/modules file but I don't what to enter??

Edit: To get webcam working after boot, in terminal:

1. sudo nano -w /etc/modules or sudo gedit /etc/modules
2. add 'facetimehd' on a new line (without quotes).
3. Save and reboot..

Answer (score 1):

If it still gives error try the following for ubuntu 18.04 , Macbook pro worked like a charm

```
cd /etc/local/src
$ git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
$ cd bcwc_pcie/firmware
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ cd ..
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install   (Update with make install for 18.04) 
$ sudo depmod
$ sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
$ sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

Comment: This fixed problem on Ubuntu 19.04 and MacBook pro i7 mid 2015.