# How do I get the MacBook Pro isight camera working on 18.04?

Tags: webcam, macbook, macbook-pro, camera

I have referenced the thread at: [MacBook Pro camera not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051079/macbook-pro-camera-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

It lists the following steps:

```
cd /etc/local/src
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie/firmware
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo make
sudo install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

I had the camera working, but forgot what I did. After an update, the camera stopped working.

I just followed the above steps except for the `sudo install` didn't work, so I did `sudo make install`.

I am now getting the following error when I try to sudo modprobe facetimehd:

```
wayne@MacBookUbuntu:~/Downloads/bcwc_pcie$ sudo modprobe facetimehd
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'facetimehd': Exec format error
```

Also is there a way to make the change permanent once fixed?

Comment: Update: It works. Apparently all the steps above work if you substitute sudo make install for sudo install.  I rebooted and did a fresh download and the steps worked. I had been trying to save myself a step by using the old download.

Comment: **Edit:  updated steps above for people who don't read the comments

Comment: This question just gets worse and worse all the time and I'm starting to believe that the continual deterioration is inevitable. I tried to reject a previous conflicting edit, but I didn't succeed because two other editors overrode me and accepted it anyway. You wrote in the 5th paragraph that `sudo install` didn't work (obviously not) so what's the sense of degrading the original source except to purposefully create confusion? More importantly `sudo make` command is a nightmare from a security point of view. The correct command is `make` without `sudo`.

Comment: At this point your question is so full of errors that I can't fix it, because it's your question and I don't want to vandalize it. It's quite the opposite in fact. The easiest thing for you to do would be to visit the [revisions page](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1094973/revisions) and rollback your question to a better earlier revision. One mouse click and you're done. I tried to prevent this disaster from occurring but unfortunately I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this in the future, you need to run a `make clean` on both the facetime firmware and bdc_pci.  So...

```
cd facetimehd-firmware/
make clean
make
sudo make install

cd ../bcwc_pcie/
make clean
make
sudo make install

sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo vim /etc/modules
```

then make sure that `facetimehd` is still written into your modules file.

Hope this helps!