# isight camera (mac) works on hangouts, not skype in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, skype, webcam, macbook-pro

I installed the isight camera drivers according to this thread: [How do I get the MacBook Pro isight camera working on 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094973/how-do-i-get-the-macbook-pro-isight-camera-working-on-18-04?rq=1)

The camera works on Google Hangouts but not with Skype. Skype audio and video settings say 'Apple Facetime HD' for camera, however it shows a black screen and the green camera led does not light up as it does when using hangouts.

I have already reinstalled skype.

Any reason the camera would work, but not with skype?