# Mac Pro dont see camera

Tags: 20.04, macbook-pro, camera

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I cant see the camera. I tried the recommendations for 16.04 but it didn't work. Any help ?

Comment: What are the outputs of `lspci` and `lsusb`? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1297916/edit) your question to add these information.

Comment: If you have a MacBook Pro from between 2011 and 2015, [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188105/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-does-not-recognise-my-macbook-onboard-camera) may solve your problem. It’s a bit of work, but I can confirm from experience that it does resolve the issue.